# Explanation needed, applyAsync with nested allOf treats CompletionStage as finished

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

In my app I have 3 future calls, that are done in parallel and when a response for one of them is received, I have another 3 requests that all should finish before proceeding with code execution, precisely the `DeferredResult` from spring.

After a while, I realized that page is sometimes rendered before the latter 3 requests are done. Original source code (ommited logic for simplicity):

```
public DeferredResult<String> someControllerMethod() {

    DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult();

    CompletableFuture.allOf(
        future1(),
        future2(),
        future3()
    )
    .whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> result.setResult("something"));

    return result;
}

public CompletableFuture<?> future3() {
    return someService.asyncCall()
        .thenApplyAsync(response -> {
            ....
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(
                future4(),
                future5(),
                future6()
            );
        }
    );
}
```

With `thenApplyAsync` sometimes `DeferredResult` is completed before actual future, while changing to `thenComposeAsync` seems solve the issue. Could someone explain me why? Or it's a bug in my code somewhere and it should not behave this way?

Comment: They way you use it, is wrong, and the way you have posted, it even generates a compiler error pointing to it. Obviously, your real code must be different.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thenApply[Async]` accepts a function that evaluates to an arbitrary value. Once the value has been returned, the future will be completed with that value. When the function, like in your code, returns another future, this doesn’t add an additional meaning to it, the future will be the result value, whether completed or not, just like any other object.

In fact, your

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> future3() {
    return someService.asyncCall()
        .thenApplyAsync(response -> {
            ....
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(
                future4(),
                future5(),
                future6()
            );
        }
    );
}
```

method does not even compile, as the result is `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Void>>`, a future whose result value is another future. The only way not to spot the error, is to use a broader type, e.g. `CompletableFuture<Object>` or `CompletableFuture<?>`, as the return type of `future3()`.

In contrast, `thenCompose[Async]` expects a function that evaluates to another future, to exactly the outcome you expect. That’s the fundamental different between “apply” and “compose”. If you keep the specific `CompletableFuture<Void>` return type for `future3()`, the compiler already guides you to use “compose”, as only that will be accepted.

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> future3() {
    return someService.asyncCall()
        .thenComposeAsync(response -> {
            ....
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(
                future4(),
                future5(),
                future6()
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Java doc is not helpful with understanding this, thanks for clarification. Indeed my code looks different, I made some shortcuts, but we can assume that I use `CompletableFuture<?>`